# How to implement SMS blacklist for Android 4.4 and higher?

Tags: android, sms, android-4.4-kitkat, android-broadcast

In accordance with [the doc](http://android-developers.blogspot.ru/2013/10/getting-your-sms-apps-ready-for-kitkat.html):

> Note that—beginning with Android 4.4—any attempt by your app to abort
>   the SMS_RECEIVED_ACTION broadcast will be ignored so all apps
>   interested have the chance to receive it.

In order to implement blacklist for incoming SMS, my app should act as Default SMS app. But I don't want my app to be real default SMS app. So, I am thinking about the following solution:

**1.** user assigns my app as default SMS app in Android settings;

**2.** user choose another (real) SMS app in my application;

**3.** so, my app is able to stop SMS_RECEIVED_ACTION broadcast for spam SMS, but

**4.** all normal SMS should be passed to real SMS app.

So, I have two questions -

**1.** How to get the full list of apps, which could be assigned as default
    SMS apps (Android somehow shows only particular apps in the
    Preferences)?

**2.** How to pass further processing of incoming messages, message
    creations etc. to real default SMS app?

Comment: Since the "real default SMS app" will be unable to write to the `Sms` content provider, I rather doubt that your plan will work.

Comment: @CommonsWare, hmm, right. Does it mean there is no way to have blacklist app with Android 4.4? (unless it is built-in function of default SMS app)

Comment: I am not aware of a way to implement a blacklist, except as part of a full SMS client.

Answer (score 0):

you can get this list of application check all the application which have SMS SEND/RECEIVE permission and that a potential real SMS apps

```
public abstract int checkPermission (String permName, String pkgName)
```

method of package Manager can help

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#checkPermission(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)